# Set button id to state when clicked

Tags: reactjs

**Goal:** Grab button id `9:00am` and set it as state with `setTime`

I'm using a functional component:

```js
function Appointment() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState();

  const handleTime = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    setTime(id);
    console.log(id);
  };
```

And here is the code that grabs the id:

```js
<div className="appointment__timeSlots">
            <button
              className="appointment__button"
              id="9:00am"
              onClick={handleTime}
            >
              9:00am
            </button>
          </div>
```

**NOTE** My console log isn't printing anything which is making it very hard to debug.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pass an anonymous function with the button event as arguments

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick is not passing the event to your function.
Should be

```
onClick={(e)=>
{this.handleTime(e)}});
```

Comment: How would I do this with a functional component?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it perfectly works... Hope you are writing it correctly as below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function Appointment() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState();

  const handleTime = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    setTime(id);
    console.log(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="appointment__timeSlots">
      <button className="appointment__button" id="9:00am" onClick={handleTime}>
        9:00am
      </button>
      <p>{time}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Appointment />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Still not working. When i console log, I get "undefined" even after I click the button

Comment: The code block I provided actually worked in my machine. Try to console.log your "e" to confirm.